# How to filter results of model based on contents of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've got two models with a one-to-many relationship between them:
reservation belongs to one company. A company can have multiple reservations.

I know want to query all the reservations where the company has a certain parameter set. So I tried this query but it works only partly. It discards the excluded company-info but it doesn't throw out the reservation from the result set.

```
$result = Reservations::with(['company' => function($query) {
   $query->where('kind_of','=','r');
 }])->get();
```

It still returns the reservations which do not meet the where-clause in the with statement. Only the additional-eager loaded data is not being loaded anymore.

How am I able to exclude the reservations which match the sql-clause:

```
... WHERE company.kind_of = 'r'
```

Comment: Essentially you're loading all the Reservations, with Company details that match the query.
What you want is to load the Companies, filtered by the query, and their respective Reservations.
Basically, try it the other way around and see how you get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `whereHas` method to perform a query based on the existence of a relationship, and also you need to then remember to eager load the company itself using `with`.

```
$result = Reservations::whereHas('company', function($query) {
   $query->where('kind_of','r');
 })->with('company')->get();
```

Comment: Damn. I tried the whereHas() method, but I used company.kind_of as the first parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$result = Company::with('reservations')->where('kind_of','=','r')->get();
```

Comment: This produces, obviously, another list: company's with per company a list of reservations. I want a list of all the reservations queried on the relation-parameter.